# Specific character count in string

Tags: javascript, sorting

So guys, I want to make a specific character counter, f.g. in word Specific we have 2 "i". Where am I wrong?

```
function countChar(word, char) {
  var count = 0
  for (let i = 0; i <= word.lenght; i++) {
    if (word[i] === `${char}`) {
      count += 1
    }
  }
  return count;
}
console.log(countChar("BBC","B"));
//0
//undefined
```

Comment: Does this help?: "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)"

Comment: Typo: word.length instead of word.lenght

Comment: ... and word[i] instead of string[i] in the comparison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems in your code:

- typo word.length instead of word.lenght
- word[i] instead of string[i] in the comparison

So, your code works when you use

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function countChar(word, char) {
  var count = 0
  for (let i = 0; i <= word.length; i++) {
    if (word[i] === `${char}`) {
      count += 1
    }
  }
  return count;
}
alert (countChar("BBC","B"));
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Please use a debugger, like the ones that are contained in every modern browser in the future ;-).

Answer (score 0):

There is a typing mistake in for loop. Write length instead of lenght.

Here is working code

```
function countChar(word, char) {
    var count = 0
    for (let i = 0; i <= word.length; i++) {
        if (word[i] === `${char}`) {
            count += 1
        }
    }
    return count;
}
console.log(countChar("BBC","B"));
```